# Unable to add sysdig plugin in grafana dashboard

Tags: docker, kubernetes, monitoring, grafana, sysdig

I have installed grafana in kubernetes cluster and i am trying to add sysdig datasource.
But,it shows sysdig plugin not found, i tried setting up grafana with sysdig plugin using below command:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name grafana sysdiglabs/grafana:latest
```

But, i am unable to open grafana dashboard in browser using :

```
http://localhost:3000
```

I also installed grafana in kubernetes cluster as below:

```
kubectl get services -n monitoring                                   
NAME                 TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)          AGE
grafana              NodePort   179.9.17.16   192.168.1.23   3000:32001/TCP   96m
prometheus-service   NodePort   172.29.3.43     <none>         8080:30000/TCP   6d21h
```

I used sysdiglabs/grafana:latest image in above but still unable to find the sysdig plugin in grafana datasource.

In local laptop setup of grafana works and shows sysdig plugin , but i want to use grafana installed in cluster with sysdig plugin. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I did it using LoadBalancer. Cluster firewall settings was causing the connectivity issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following link (https://docs.sysdig.com/en/configure-sysdig-with-grafana.html) and I was able to get Sysdig metrics into Grafana.
[image]

Can you check if you have already defined the authentication:

[image]

Comment: I am following the same. document but can you please tell me, which step you followed for adding sysdig plugin in grafana . Are you installing grafana in cluster or standalone VM?

Comment: I am using prometheus datasource. In fact, Sysdig expose Prometheus API:  https://app.sysdigcloud.com/prometheus then I configure the Custom http header with (Header: Authorization and Value: Bearer YOUR-SYSDIG-TOKEN
). I am installing the Grafana plugin as a docker image: docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 --name grafana grafana/grafana

Comment: I executed docker image: docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 --name grafana grafana/grafana, but unable to access grafana from browser, i tried localhost:3000

Comment: This is seems more a connectivity issue then. Can you try: http://192.168.1.23:32001. I see that you are using NodePort to define the Grafana service